# How to get a grip on several extremly large numbers at the same time?

Tags: python

Say, you have 100 50-digit numbers that look like this:

> 37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250
>   46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538
>   74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629
>
> ...

I would like to get a grip on all of them in order to make a calculation. I know one way to do this is to convert them into single strings like this:

> "37107287533902102798797998220837590246510135740250"
>   "46376937677490009712648124896970078050417018260538"
>   "74324986199524741059474233309513058123726617309629"

But it would take a lot of time to do this for every single number. Is there any way to do this quickly?

Comment: `sum(re.findall('[0-9]+'), data)` something along these lines.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What does it mean "to get a grip on them"? Why would it take a long time to convert 100 50-digit numbers to strings, and why would it be more convenient to represent numbers as strings instead of ints?

Comment: What do you mean, "get a grip" on them? What do you actually want to do with them? And where are they coming from in the first place?

Comment: I would like to work with them in my IDE, so it's easier to convert them to a string first and then just use the parts I need. Otherwise, I would have to declare a single variable for every single number, wouldn't I?